# UserManager.AddToRole(User.Id, "Members") but User.IsInRole("Members") is delayed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

**Using VS 2013, standard MVC template**

I have:

```
UserManager.AddToRole(User.Id, "Members");
```

Then, the code flows to:

```
if (!User.IsInRole("Members")) ...
```

This will return false, even though I can confirm that at that point the `User.Id` is in `dbo.AspNetUserRoles` for Members.

However, if the user were to re-log in again, then `User.IsInRole("Members")` will return true.

Is there some caching?  Why the delay?  How do I overcome it?

Comment: Think about when the properties of the User get populated. Clearly you need to either wait until the properties get repopulated, or use some other way of checking the role. If you just added the role to the user, you can assume the user is in the role and there's no need to check.

Comment: There is an [async method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613290(v=vs.108).aspx) on the User Manager for determining if a user is in a role.

Comment: @mason Regarding your first comment, the test of IsInRole is not in the same action, but after a RedirectToAction.  So it is a different Http request altogether, but somehow IsInRole will return false.

Comment: Your question did not make that clear. You said "the code flows to". Realize that we have no idea how your application is put together, and it's up to you to clearly explain the issue.

Comment: I will re-start a new question.